# 'sh: sh: command not found' When using withCredentials block in multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a Jenkins multibranch pipeline to build an iOS app to Crashlytics using Fastlane. Right now, the API key and build secret for Crashlytics are stored in plaintext in my Fastfile, so I wanted to move them to Jenkins credentials so that information isn't available to anyone who gets access to my GitHub repo.

I followed the instructions detailed [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs#inpipelines) to create the credentials  and access them from the Jenkinsfile. I created them as 'Secret text' type credentials. Here is what they look like in Jenkins (don't have enough rep to post images so have some links):
[api token credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZp7o.png)
[build secret credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZGDx.png)

Here is how I access those credentials in my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        ...
        stage('Deploy Patient App') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                    string(credentialsId: 'crashlytics_api', variable: 'api_token'),
                    string(credentialsId: 'crashlytics_build', variable: 'build_secret')
                ]) {
                    sh '''
                        set +x
                        bundle exec fastlane deploy app:\'Therapy\' api_token:$api_token build_secret:$build_secret
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the pipeline in Jenkins, I get this output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Patient App)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $api_token or $build_secret
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
sh: sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong in my Jenkinsfile? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

I'm also new here, but I thought I'd see if I can help...

I did some research and came across this:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-credentials-plugin/issues/22#issuecomment-317203165

Although this is for another plugin, I noticed the similarities are that they're also using a declarative pipeline and they didn't require a `script {}` block.

Substitution of the difference from the Github comment, with your code, is as follows:

```
stage('Deploy Patient App') {
    steps {
        withCredentials([
            string(credentialsId: 'crashlytics_api', variable: 'api_token'),
            string(credentialsId: 'crashlytics_build', variable: 'build_secret')
        ]) {
            sh 'bundle exec fastlane deploy app:\'Therapy\' api_token:$api_token build_secret:$build_secret'
        }
    }
}
```

Another suggestion said to use double quotes `" "`, otherwise they would receive `script.sh: Bad substitution` error.

PS: Apologies, I couldn't test this code myself, but it did get a lot of upvotes on Github. Hope this helps!